# Jordan Cell as Jordan Form implies Commuting Matrices are in Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $X$ is a matrix such that its Jordan form is a single Jordan cell, then show that all matrices $Y$ that commute with $X$ are polynomials in $X$ (there is a polynomial $f$ such that $Y=f(X)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline of proof:** It suffices to show that
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&1\\&0&1\\&&\ddots\\&&&0}
$$
commutes with a matrix $A$ if and only if $A$ has the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{
a_0&a_1&a_2&\cdots\\
&a_0&a_1 & \cdots\\
&&\ddots&\ddots\\
\\
&&&&a_0} = 
a_{n-1}J^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 J + a_0I
$$
(this can be done by computation). From there, we note that the matrix $B$ commutes with $S(J + \lambda I)S^{-1}$ if and only if $S^{-1}BS$ commutes with $J$.

---

In response to your comment: confirm that for arbitrary matrices $A,B$, $I$ the identity, and $\lambda \in \Bbb C$, we have
$$
AB = BA \iff (A + \lambda I)B = B(A + \lambda I)
$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18797/discussion-on-answer-by-omnomnomnom-jordan-cell-as-jordan-form-implies-commuting).